# toggling effect in jquery by default

Tags: jquery

My requirement is: when I click a li, its 'p' siblings should be slide down, and on the consecutive click it should slide up. I achieved it through the following code. But by default the 'p' gets slided down. Only when I click the slide up/down is working. I want the p elements to be slided up(hidden) by default. How to achieve this?

HTML:

```
 <ul id = "duration">
        <li id="time">Time</li>
        <p><input type="text" id="from" /></p>
        <p><input type="text" id="to" /></p>
    </ul>
```

JQUERY:

```
  $(function(){
     $('ul #time').toggle(function(){
        $("#duration p").show("slow");
    },
    function(){
        $("#duration p").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: simple `$('ul #time').toggle()` helps?`

Comment: `$("#duration p").css("display",'none');` try adding this as first line in `$(function(){)`

Comment: I don't understand, you are saying _when I click the slide up/down is working_ but in the code you have provided you are using show/hide!! How're you able to slide up/down using show/hide???

Comment: @Let'sCode Thanks, your suggestion works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just hide them at the start of your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#duration p").hide();
});
```

Comment: +1 You could also do this with CSS `#duration p { display: none }`

Comment: @FDL Yours is similar to that of Let'sCode suggestion..Yes you are right..I guess it will also work..Thanks..anyways

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$("#duration p").toggle();
$(document).on("click", '#time', function(){
    $("#duration p").toggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: This one works fine:$("#duration p").toggle();
$(document).click('#time', function(){
    $("#duration p").toggle("slow");
});

Answer (score 0):

`$("#duration p").css("display",'none');`

try adding this as first line in `$(function(){)`

This will make all `p` hidden by default